# PhoneGap ChildBrowser ontop Android

Tags: android, cordova

Im using PhoneGap ChildBrowser.

I got this top menu bar in HTML, below the menu bar i got placeholder there im loading my ChildBrowser.

Everything works as it should, except. When im click on the top menu bar to change the content of childbrowser nothing happens, its looks like the childbrowser is above the HTML-code.

I can see the menu but not click it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is because the ChildBrowser is a modal dialog display above your application. Can you post a screen shot so I can see what you are trying to do and maybe I can give you a suggestion?